# Softlayer service call to "getSnapshotPercentage" is failing

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I wrote the following logic to [get the Snapshot Percentage](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/getSnapshotPercentage), and am getting the below error. NOTE, I have tried this with both the `Network_Storage`, and `Network_Storage_Iscsi` and am seeing the same response for both cases. Is there a workaround or is this a bug?

```
def get_snapshot_space(sl_config, iscsi_identifier):
    """ get the total number of Snapshot Space remaining"""
    snapshot_percentage = SL.instance(sl_config).net.getSnapshotPercentage(id=iscsi_identifier);
    print "Snapshot Space Used: \% %s " % snapshot_space;
```

ERROR:

```
 snapshot_percentage = SL.instance(sl_config).net.getSnapshotPercentage(id=iscsi_identifier);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer-5.1.0-
py2.7.egg/SoftLayer/API.py", line 375, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer-5.1.0-

py2.7.egg/SoftLayer/API.py", line 343, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer-5.1.0-

py2.7.egg/SoftLayer/API.py", line 246, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer-5.1.0-

py2.7.egg/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 187, in __call__
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(Client): Function ("getSnapshotPercentage") is not a valid method for this service
```

Also, I have noticed that on the softLayer Portal, the representation of the percentage is incorrect sometimes? It's been well over an hour since I have cleared all snapshots.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is currently deprecated so you could use an object mask to retrieve the **bytesUsed** and **snapshotCapacityGb** attributes.

The next script generates the snapshot space available that's displayed in the UI portal.

```
"""
Retrieves snapshot space.

See below references for more details.
Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage
@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
networkStorageService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage']

iscsiStorageId = 1234567
objectMask = 'mask[snapshotCapacityGb,snapshots[bytesUsed,snapshotSizeBytes,snapshotSpaceAvailable]]'

try:
    storage = networkStorageService.getObject(mask=objectMask, id=iscsiStorageId)
    capacity = long(float(storage['snapshotCapacityGb'])) * 1e+9
    used_space = 0
    for child in storage['snapshots']:
        used_space = used_space + long(float(child['snapshotSizeBytes']))
    snapshot_space = (capacity - used_space) / 1e+9    
    print snapshot_space   
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print('Failed ... faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
        % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Regarding the snapshot space representation in the UI, it's updated each hour more or less.

I hope this could help you.