# How to calculate softlayer Snapshot size?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In previous posts, I have asked how to calculate the snapshot capacity. I have tried to work out how to calculate a snapshot size prior to taking it and have not been successful. Do you know if there is a way to do this?

- [How to get snapshot space left on device.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211667/softlayer-service-call-to-getsnapshotpercentage-is-failing)

Answer (score 0):

A snapshot is the difference between two points in time, it actually depends on how much changes at time.

Initially a snapshot will be zero size, because it takes no information to roll back to literally one second ago, if no data is being deleted or modified.

Any time data is modified or deleted, which was present at the time the snapshot was taken, the snapshot grows to hold that data. I'm afraid to say that there is not an specific method to get the information that you want.